# mysql select row then copy row and update values

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Is there a mysql syntax that can preform a select values from a table, then copy those values into the same table, but update a few columns of the copy?

Table (`ticket`s), `id` is primary key, auto_increment:

```
id | name | start_date | end_date | value | active
```

- Select a single row from tickets given a few values like `name`, `start_date`, `end_date` and `value`
- Copy the row that matches the statement but update the value by `x`
- Insert the copy with the update

Comment: INSERT INTO tickets SELECT * FROM tickets t WHERE t.start_date = ? AND t.end_date = ? AND t.name = ? AND t.value = ? SET t.value = ? also with a duplicate key update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will insert a copy of any row(s) matching the criteria in the SELECT..WHERE statement, with the new row(s) having their prim key id autogenerated as per your spec.

```
INSERT INTO `tickets`(`name`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `value`, `active`)    
SELECT `name`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `value`+[value_modifier], `active`
FROM `tickets`
WHERE `name`       = '[name value]' AND
      `start_date` = [start_date]   AND  -- assuming date is timestamp otherwise wrap in '
      `end_date`   = [end_date]     AND
      `value`      = [some_value]        -- assuming value is number
```

If it was a matter of just needing to update -but not copy- rows that match certain criteria then obviously you'd just use an UPDATE statement

Comment: The query works. The weird thing is that the value that was allready in the database updates and the copy contains the old value. I think I will tweak it a bit so that it will update the value of the copy

Comment: yes, I think that the unique key and on duplicate key update were redudant so I've removed them in the edit. Just changing the value field within the select statement will work as intended

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you are up-to, may be this will help?

```
INSERT INTO tickets SELECT t.startdate,t.endate, 'x' value FROM tickets t WHERE t.start_date = ? AND t.end_date = ? AND t.name = ? AND t.value = ?
```